# Scroll a JScrollPane to a specific row on a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JTable Scrolling to a specified row index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853020/jtable-scrolling-to-a-specified-row-index)

I have a JTable and I programmatically need to select a row by using this code:

```
  myTable.setRowSelectionInterval(i, j);
```

(where i and j are valid row and column numbers respectively).

The problem is, when you jump to a row, the JScrollPane does not move.
In this case, the table is quite long, and often the "selected row" is not visible on the screen, so the user has to stay scrolling up/down manually to find it. I would like to know how I can make the JScrollPane automatically jump to the specific location of the row.

Edit: Found this one liner which can do it:

```
table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(row,0, true));
```

Comment: that not works as I expected too, put that to the code that I posted, you have to move with JViewPort correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just extends post by @Eng.Fouad +1, no works as I exactly expected (with kind help by [StanislavL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301607/stanislavl) from another Java Swing forum)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableSelectionGood implements ListSelectionListener {

    private JTable[] tables;
    private boolean ignore = false;

    public TableSelectionGood() {
        Object[][] data1 = new Object[100][5];
        Object[][] data2 = new Object[50][5];
        Object[][] data3 = new Object[50][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
            data1[i][0] = "Company # " + (i + 1);
            for (int j = 1; j < data1[i].length; j++) {
                data1[i][j] = "" + (i + 1) + ", " + j;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
            data2[i][0] = "Company # " + ((i * 2) + 1);
            for (int j = 1; j < data2[i].length; j++) {
                data2[i][j] = "" + ((i * 2) + 1) + ", " + j;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < data3.length; i++) {
            data3[i][0] = "Company # " + (i * 2);
            for (int j = 1; j < data3[i].length; j++) {
                data3[i][j] = "" + (i * 2) + ", " + j;
            }
        }
        String[] headers = {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3", "Col 4", "Col 5"};
        DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel(data1, headers);
        DefaultTableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel(data2, headers);
        DefaultTableModel model3 = new DefaultTableModel(data3, headers);
        final JTable jTable1 = new JTable(model1);
        jTable1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        final JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane();
        sp1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        sp1.setViewportView(jTable1);
        final JTable jTable2 = new JTable(model2);
        jTable2.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        final JScrollPane sp2 = new JScrollPane();
        sp2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        sp2.setViewportView(jTable2);
        final JTable jTable3 = new JTable(model3);
        jTable3.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        final JScrollPane sp3 = new JScrollPane();
        sp3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        sp3.setViewportView(jTable3);
        TableSelectionGood tableSelection = new TableSelectionGood(jTable1, jTable2, jTable3);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0, 10, 10));
        panel1.add(sp1);
        panel1.add(sp2);
        panel1.add(sp3);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("tableSelection");
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public TableSelectionGood(JTable... tables) {
        for (JTable table : tables) {
            table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(this);
        }
        this.tables = tables;
    }

    private JTable getTable(Object model) {
        for (JTable table : tables) {
            if (table.getSelectionModel() == model) {
                return table;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void changeSelection(JTable table, String rowKey) {
        int col = table.convertColumnIndexToView(0);
        for (int row = table.getRowCount(); --row >= 0;) {
            if (rowKey.equals(table.getValueAt(row, col))) {
                table.changeSelection(row, col, false, false);
                return;
            }
        }
        table.clearSelection();
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() || ignore) {
            return;
        }
        ignore = true;
        try {
            JTable table = getTable(e.getSource());
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            String rowKey = table.getValueAt(row, table.convertColumnIndexToView(0)).toString();
            for (JTable t : tables) {
                if (t == table) {
                    continue;
                }
                changeSelection(t, rowKey);
                JViewport viewport = (JViewport) t.getParent();
                Rectangle rect = t.getCellRect(t.getSelectedRow(), 0, true);
                Rectangle r2 = viewport.getVisibleRect();
                t.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(rect.x, rect.y, (int) r2.getWidth(), (int) r2.getHeight()));
                System.out.println(new Rectangle(viewport.getExtentSize()).contains(rect));
            }
        } finally {
            ignore = false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TableSelectionGood tableSelection = new TableSelectionGood();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I used this in my old project:

```
public static void scrollToVisible(JTable table, int rowIndex, int vColIndex)
{
    if (!(table.getParent() instanceof JViewport)) return;
    JViewport viewport = (JViewport)table.getParent();
    Rectangle rect = table.getCellRect(rowIndex, vColIndex, true);
    Point pt = viewport.getViewPosition();
    rect.setLocation(rect.x-pt.x, rect.y-pt.y);
    viewport.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
}
```

Reference: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/Vis.html

Comment: Exact copy of [JTable Scrolling to a specified row index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853020/jtable-scrolling-to-a-specified-row-index)'s answer.

Comment: @Jeffrey Thanks Jeffery for the link. I used this code in the past and I forget where I got it from

Comment: After using this code for a while, I found it to be a bit buggy with long tables. I found a nice one liner though:
                table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(row,0, true));