# JScrollPane Movement Restriction Query?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have JTable of order nxn with the JScrollPane size being

```
JScrollPane jsc = new JScrollPane(table);
        jsc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,700));
```

The Scenario is this:: whenever I edit the last cell (it contains a JTextField) of the JTable by dragging down the ScrollBar and come out of Focus, the ScrollBar slides back the original position, i.e the beginning position. I would like the ScrollBar be in the place where it was set by the user before and after editing.... how can this be achieved?

Thank You In Advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can able to determine `scrollToVisible(JTable table, int rowIndex, int vColIndex)`, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052634/scroll-a-jscrollpane-to-a-specific-row-on-a-jtable/7052751#7052751)

Answer (score 2):

Because [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) is a [Scrolling-Savvy Client](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable), it implements the [`Scrollable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface. You may get better results using the method [`setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) instead of calling `setPreferredSize()` directly on the scroll pane.

Comment: setPreferredScrollableViewportSize() +1,