# Choose what rows are shown in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable and, inside its TableModel, I saved an int; this is the row index that I want my view to "keep in the middle" of the Viewport.
What I mean is that, for example, if I have 1000 rows, 10 are shown in the View at any time and my index is 500, I want my vieport to automatically show rows 495-504.
These rows are **not** necessarily selected.
I hope I was able to explain my problem properly.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your row heights are the same,

```
int rowPosition = index - 10 / 2;
int pixelPosition = rowPosition * table.getRowHeight(rowPosition);
scrollPane.getViewPort().setViewPosition(new Point(0, pixelPosition));
```

If the row heights aren't the same, you would have to sum all of the row heights from row 1 to row index - 5.

Comment: Instead of table.getHeight(), try scrollPane.getViewPort().getExtentSize().

Answer (score 3):

1) `JTable` (notice can by caused by `Filtering`) returns number of rows

2) each of row can returns [Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)

3) put this `Rectangle` to the [JScrollPane#scrollRectToVisible(Rectangle aRect)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) wrapped into invokeLater(), simple example about moving JViewport to the decision row [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7052751/714968)